# Icons for InfraRecorder don't show in the start menu after installing?

Tags: installation, icons, start-menu, burning

I have been stumped on this for a few days now. Has anyone that uses InfraRecorder solved it?
I've uninstalled the application, deleted %aAPPDATA%, and reinstalled. I've even did the "reinstall" from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: you didn't run the installer 'As Administrator', did you?

Comment: No I didn't there isn't an option for it. Maybe because it's an .msi ?

Comment: why don't you use the portable version and throw a shortcut into the start menu? Installation isn't really required as there is no file association or DLL registration involved.

Comment: Yea that works. I just mailed them and let them know the issue with the MSI installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the regular 32 bit version. It was a Nullsoft installer with options to install the icons. That works but it doesn't reinstall my icons.